# Doing a Normalization

Tags: normalization

**Full Question image:**

[image]

**3NF image:**

[image]

**2NF image:**

[image]

Hey, I have to change this to 3NF & 2NF. I tried it myself but i'm not too sure if I am right or not.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rQSPe4Q.png Here's a picture of my 2nf, i hope posting these links is allowed.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive about what exactly is the problem and what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the Job_Class from the original question.

2nf will include 3 tables. That's because consider CHG_Hours. It depends on Job_class. There can be a candidate key Employee_num, Employee name and Job_class and CHG_Hours depend on a proper subset of this candidate key i.e Job_class. Hence we need to separate it.

1) CHG hours

```
CHG HOURS | JOB_CLASS
```

2) Employee

```
Employee_num | Employ name | Hours
```

3) Project

```
Project_num | Project name
```

3nf:

Same, because each column depends solely on the primary key. The primary keys have underscores.

Comment: Both the 3NF and 2NF will have the same information ?

Comment: 3NF says that there must be no transitive functional dependancy i.e, Every column must be directly dependent on the primary key. it should not be indirectly dependent on it... for e.g  consider employee address in table #2 then employee_address is indirectly depndent on primary key "employee_num" via employee_name. 

I don't think Hours is indirectly dependent on employee_num.